# Compare two Dictionary<keyvaluepair<string,string>,int>

Tags: c#, dictionary

I am stuck in problem of comparing two dictionaries for similarity.

I have two dictionaries of type `Dictionary<KeyValuePair<string,string>,int>`,i.e

```
{
   [(a,b),1],
   **[(a,c),4]**,
   [(a,d),5]
}    
{
   [(x,y),5],
   **[(x,c),10]**,
   [(x,z),2]
}
```

I want to compare above two dictionaries which results in another dictionary of output:

```
{
   [(a,c),4],
   [(x,c),10]
}
```

Comment: Why do you have this specific result? Is it because the `c` is in both KeyValuePairs?

Comment: I am not sure why you expect that result. Can you tell us about the algorithm?

Comment: yes i want to trace such combinations in which key or value exist in both dictionaries

Comment: "yes i want to trace such combinations in which key or value exist in both dictionaries" - but in that case, why is (a,d),5 and (x,y),5 not in the new dictionary?

Comment: I believe you would better create a data structure for this, override Equals and GetHashCode for it and use built-in comparison mechanisms.

Comment: @Tyress i want to trace key or value of KeyvaluePair<string,string> in Dictionary<KeyvaluePair<string,string>,int>

Comment: I also dount a Dictionary of KeyValuePairs is the whrong structure for this (just notice that strange name...). Create a simple DTO-class for this as rederick also suggests.

Comment: However, what exactly DOES the algorithm do? Does it only compare the value-part of the KeyValuePairs for equality and then adds the correpsonding KVs to your dictionary?

Comment: Both key and value parts

Comment: And where are "both, key AND value" are equal on `(a, c)` and `(x, c)`?

Comment: What means you want to _trace_ combinations. Also, your result dict contains two key value pairs which dont appear in **both** source dictionaries but only in one of them them.

Comment: This is Dictionary Dictionary<KeyValuePair<string,string>,int>. In want to compare KeyValuePair<string,string> of two dictionaries for Key and value part.

Comment: Ok, please explain why `[(a,c),4]` equals `[(x,c),10]`, whilst the others don´t? The only part they have in common is `c`, which is only the VALUE of your KVP, however the KEYS are different (namely `a` and `x`).

Comment: @seeSharp: please provide a better sample, the expected result is not related to your source dictionaries as Himbrombeere has explained. If it is you have not explained the logic at all.

Comment: @seeSharp Using a `KeyValuePair` as `Key` of a `Dictionary` is very confusing, since the `Dictionary` itself creates a `KeyValuePair` of the Key and Value types provided. Maybe you should change the type to `Tuple`.

Comment: @Domysee: a tuple is not better, then use a real class in the first place and override `Equals` + `GetHashCode`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I agree a Tuple is not ideal, but at least the Key/Value ambiguity would be gone.

Comment: @Domysee: that's not a problem if the logic would be clear. What is really confusing is that the sample dictionaries seem to be not related to the expected result.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - If you're recommending to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in a _**class**_ then you should also recommend that the class have _**read-only**_ properties otherwise the implementation will be incorrect.

Comment: @seeSharp - It would be awfully nice if your sample data is presented as valid c# code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're only matching on the `.Key.Value` so does this work for you:

```
var dic1 = new Dictionary<KeyValuePair<string, string>, int>()
{
    { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("a", "b"), 1 },
    { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("a", "c"), 4 },
    { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("a", "d"), 5 },
};

var dic2 = new Dictionary<KeyValuePair<string, string>, int>()
{
    { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("x", "y"), 5 },
    { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("x", "c"), 10 },
    { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("x", "z"), 2 },
};

var query =
    from kvp1 in dic1
    join kvp2 in dic2 on kvp1.Key.Value equals kvp2.Key.Value
    from kvp in new [] { kvp1, kvp2 }
    select kvp;

var result = query.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

That gives me:

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks Enigmativity. This is called problem solving.Every one suggesting me to change data structure.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you, you want to get all values where the `Key` or `Value` of the `KeyValuePair<string,string>` is the same. For this purpose you can use the `Intersect` method with a custom `IEqualityComparer`, as demonstrated below:

```
class Comparer : IEqualityComparer<KeyValuePair<KeyValuePair<string,string>, int>>
{
    // Products are equal if their names and product numbers are equal.
    public bool Equals(KeyValuePair<KeyValuePair<string,string>, int> x, KeyValuePair<KeyValuePair<string,string>, int> y)
    {
        //Check whether the compared objects reference the same data.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

        //Check whether any of the compared objects is null.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;

        //Check whether the products' properties are equal.
        return x.Key.Key == y.Key.Key || x.Key.Value == y.Key.Value;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(KeyValuePair<string,string> kvp)
    {
        //Check whether the object is null
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(kvp, null)) return 0;

        return kvp.GetHashCode();
    }
}

//call Intersect using the custom comparer
dict1.Intersect(dict2, new Comparer());
```

Comment: You could use `dict1.Keys.Intersect(dict2.Keys, new Comparer())`. But it's not clear what OP really wants.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks. I know its not really clear, just doing a wild guess trying to help.